# GetObjectData() method is never hit when implementing ISerializable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

`XmlSerializer` never calls `GetObjcetData()` on my `ISerializable`. When is `GetObjectData()` called? Thanks!

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var thing = new Thing { Name = "Dude", Id = 1 };
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Thing));

    var sw = new StringWriter();
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, foo);
    var serializedXml = sw.ToString();

    var sr = new StringReader(serializedXml);
    var result = (Thing)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
  }        
}

public class Thing : ISerializable
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public Thing() { }        
  public Thing(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) { }

  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    // Breakpoint placed on the following line never gets hit:
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing up binary serialization and XML serialization.  ISerializable is only meaningful if you use BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

XmlSerializer doesn't call GetObjectData.  Binary and soap do.
If you want to manage xml serialization, use [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) instead